# Installing nuget package from GitHub

Tags: git, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, package-managers

The command: Install-Package curve25519-uwp 
installs version 1.0.3 of this package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/curve25519-uwp/)

On GitHub there is a version 1.0.4 that fixes a specific error I am facing.

Can anyone explain how to get that package installed?

I am using visual studio 2015 community edition with git tools installed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With NuGet, there is no way to take a pre-version from a Git repository.

You could:

1. Ask for the release of a new version of the NuGet package, or at least a pre-release.
2. Clone the repository, build the version, and replace the NuGet package with a local dependency. (Not a good solution!)
3. Like the above, but put it in your own NuGet server.
4. Manage the repository as a Git submodule.
5. Switch from NuGet to [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) which supports references toward a Git repository. (Surely the best solution if your case could appear often.)

Comment: will packet download the source code so it can be debugged?

Comment: No. None of the solution could do that. But you could use SourceLink or GitLink (there is another that I forgot the name) to do that.