# Adding GitHub project as reference in Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, github, nuget

In a .net solution, I want to add a reference to a project in github.

Is there a way to do this without the extra step of publishing the github project to nuget?

Could it be done by putting a nuget package into the git repo itself?

Comment: It is a good idea, but the current VS does not support that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could it be done by putting a nuget package into the git repo itself?

No, the repo is for source code management, it is not a binary referential like a Nuget repo.

See "[Installing nuget package from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34760754/6309)"

> With Nuget, there is no way to take a pre-version from a git repository.

If you really don't want to publish the binary to a Nuget repo, then you are in source dependency, meaning you can add that GitHub repo as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of your own Git code base, make your `.net` solution compile that submodule source code, and use the resulting package locally.